# I am getting issues with my single Post navigation in single.php with previous_post_link() and next_post_link() is not working with post type "post"

Tags: php, wordpress, post, themes

My single Post navigation in single.php with previous_post_link() and next_post_link() is not working with post type "post" but is working fine with my custom post types I have also tried get_adjacent_post_link() but of no use.

I'm getting this issue on every theme I'm activating nit just my custom theme that I'm developing.

```
<div class="pagination-single-post mt-50">
<ul class="post-pagination">
    <li><?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i> Previous Post'); ?></li>
    <li><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Not working" meaning what, exactly? Do you not get any links at all, do they point to the wrong posts, ...?

Comment: Are you really talking about posts as in blog posts - or do you maybe mean pages? https://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links#The_Next_and_Previous_Pages: _"The `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link` functions don't work on pages."_

Comment: @CBroe they are pointing to wrong posts like on post one I am getting link of last post,
And I am talking about blog posts not pages.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
if(!empty($prev_post)) {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_post->post_title . '">' . $prev_post->post_title . '</a>'; 
}

$next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);
if(!empty($next_post)) {
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_post->post_title . '">' . $next_post->post_title . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for your answer but I have already tried this method but it is not working, it is getting links of wrong posts.